# Illegal Invocation when trying to pass a file in jQuery

Tags: jquery

All,
I have the following AJAX code:

```
var ajax    = $.ajax({
    url:        ajaxurl,
    type:       options.ajaxType || 'POST',
    cache:      false,
    data:       { name: $file.data('filename'), filename: $file.data('file'), file: files, data: options.data, action: 'test_upload' },                 
    headers:    options.ajaxHeaders,
```

There are some other things after this but for readability this is the part that is causing my issue. In the data the `file: files` files is an object but I need to pass it as an object because I'm trying to simulate the contents of the $_FILES post for this.

How can I pass this as an object without getting the error message?

Comment: Use the `FormData` constructor.

Comment: I thought the names in JSON needed to be wrapped in quotes, and objects wrapped in curly braces. So perhaps adding the quotes and {} around your files object will give you the desired result.

Comment: @Vohuman I wish I could but I can't on this because that needs the `processData: false` option and I can't use that with this because I'm using wordpress and AJAX and it needs the action in the data to know what function to process the data.

Comment: Just add name to the FormData object